# How can I run pytesseract / tesseract in Foundry Code Repositories?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am trying to use the function image_to_string from the library pytesseract in a repository to perform OCR of PDFs. However, I am getting the following error:

[image]

From the checks I would assume the library was loaded correctly:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to trouble shoot here?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Foundry is not respecting / running the environment activation script
https://github.com/conda-forge/tesseract-feedstock/blob/main/recipe/activate.sh
that sets the `TESSDATA_PREFIX` environment variable automatically. However, we can infer the value manually and provide it to the pytesseract API calls.

Define the following helper function:

```
def _get_tessdata_directory_path():
    import sys
    from pathlib import Path
    env_root = Path(sys.executable).parent.parent
    share_dir = env_root / 'share' / 'tessdata'
    assert share_dir.exists(), 'tessdata directory does not exist in <envroot>/share/tessdata'
    return str(share_dir)
```

and use it like shown in the following snippet:

```
tessdata_dir_config = f'--tessdata-dir "{_get_tessdata_directory_path()}"'
pytesseract.image_to_string(image, ..., config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

Comment: Thank you for creating these. Alternatively have you tried calling this from CI shell script section? it has the downside that it can get overwritten with the auto PRs that update the configs, so you need to be careful with the merges. if you hit "Show hiden files and folders" you can see it on the ci.yml

Comment: Could you post an example how to do the above in the ci.yml? In general, we refrain from modifying the ci.yml because of the warning on top of the file... (DO NOT MODIFY OR DELETE THIS FILE.)

Comment: So the main problem with modifying the CI is that it gets overwritten whenever you upgrade your repo. I actually have no clue what to answer here. My personal opinion is that I think it should be ok for you to modify it as long as you are careful with what you are doing, and don't open support requests if the whole repo borks. I need to think about this ':)

Comment: We had this discussion with the support already. As a customer we require something that does not break with the PR upgrades, otherwise we are not gonna use it ;)

Comment: I am having the same issue, started with a pytesseract basic sample and got this error: pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH.  I'm not sure where to find path info - was your Palantir client support able to provide this to you? I also tried your function but I got the tessdata does not exist exception.

Comment: hi tessa - we are now also running into the tessdata does not exist exception. Seems like the transform update have changed the setup...

Comment: I found a new workaround, please see updated answer above.